# Complex valued integral over the real 3-sphere

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hilbert-spaces, spherical-coordinates, several-complex-variables

I would like to compute the following integral (with respect to Lebesgue measure):
$$
\int_{x\in S(\mathbb{C}^2)} \langle x | y\rangle x
$$

- Here $x\in \mathbb{C}^2$ lies on the unit hypershere of $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is alternatively the real 3-sphere $S^3$.
- $y \in \mathbb{C}^2$ as well.
- $\langle x|y\rangle = \bar{x_1}y_1 + \bar{x_2}y_2 $ is the inner product of $\mathbb{C}^2$

So the domain of this integral is the real 3-sphere and it is valued in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

How should I proceed? What parametrization of the 3-sphere should I use? The Hopf coordinates seem like a good option but are they even injective/differentiable? Will I be forced to split the sphere into several pieces so that the parametrization remains injective and differentiable for each piece (I am wanting to apply this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables))?

I feel like the answer should be proportional to $y$.
Ideally I would like to compute this integral for $\mathbb{C}^n$ instead of just $\mathbb{C}^2$.

EDIT: partially answering my question:
The answer is indeed proportional to $y$ because for any $x$ in the domain you can find a unique $x'$ such that
$$\langle x | y \rangle x + \langle x' | y \rangle x' = cy \quad (c\in \mathbb{C})$$
So the integral only adds up vectors lying on the $y$ subspace and is consequently proportional to $y$ itself. I suspect that the factor in front of $y$ is real and correspond to the area of the hypersphere $S(\mathbb{C^2})$.

Comment: What is $S(\mathbb C^2)$? Is it just $S^3$?

Comment: yes. the pairs $(u,v) \in C^2$ that satisfy $|u|^2 + |v|^2 = 1$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:\Bbb{C}^n\to\Bbb{C}^n$
\begin{align}
f(y)&:=\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\langle x|y\rangle x\, d\sigma(x),
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ is the surface measure on $S(\Bbb{C}^n)\cong S^{2n-1}$. By your convention for the inner product, $f$ is linear so it is completely determined by its values on the basis vectors $e_a=(0,\dots, 1,\dots 0)\in\Bbb{C}^n$. Now,
\begin{align}
f(e_a)&=\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\overline{x_a}\cdot x\,\,d\sigma(x)=
\left(\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\overline{x_a}x_1\,d\sigma(x),\dots, \int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\overline{x_a}x_n\,d\sigma(x)\right)
\end{align}
Thus, we're reduced to calculating the integrals $\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\overline{x_a}x_b\,d\sigma(x)$ for all $a,b\in\{1,\dots, n\}$.

If $a\neq b$, then the integral is zero, because if we consider the function $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\mapsto(x_1,\dots, -x_a,\dots, x_n)$, then the change of variables theorem introduces a minus sign in the integrand while keeping the measure and the domain $S(\Bbb{C}^n)$ the same, hence the integral is $0$ (this is the higher dimensional analogue of the fact that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval vanishes).

Suppose now that $a=b$, so that we're considering $\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}|x_a|^2\,d\sigma(x)$. Again, by symmetry, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}|x_1|^2\,d\sigma(x)=\dots =\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}|x_n|^2\,d\sigma(x).
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}|x_a|^2\,d\sigma(x)&=\frac{1}{n}\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|^2\,d\sigma(x)\\
&=\frac{A_{2n-1}}{n}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^n/\Gamma(n)}{n}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^n}{n!},
\end{align}
where $A_{k-1}=\frac{2\pi^{k/2}}{\Gamma(k/2)}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{k-1}\subset\Bbb{R}^k$ (we have also used some basic properties of the Gamma function). In other words, putting it all together, we have shown that
\begin{align}
f(e_a)&=\frac{A_{2n-1}}{n}e_a=\frac{2\pi^n}{n!}e_a,
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
f(y)&=\frac{A_{2n-1}}{n}y=\frac{2\pi^n}{n!}y.
\end{align}

Comment: (btw originally, I blindly followed my convention for the inner product so the conjugate is on $y$. In this case we have to evaluate $\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}x_ax_b\,d\sigma(x)$ for all $a,b$. It turns out this is always $0$, so using your convention, $\int_{S(\Bbb{C}^n)}\langle y|x\rangle\,x\,\,d\sigma(x)=0$ for all $y$).

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. As a side note, I tend to prefer the physics convention because it aligns well with hom functors in category theory
$$ \langle | \rangle : \bar{H} \otimes H \to \mathbb{C} $$
$$ \mathrm{hom} : \mathcal{C}^{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$$
the correspondance can be turned into something meaningful. For instance the yoneda lemma holds on the hilbert space side, and this is what you helped me prove in this question:) (thanks again)

Comment: @antoine_vm haha when I said "my convention" I really meant "the one I've used more this year". I study both math and physics, and depending on my mood/circumstance I have to alternate (and sometimes I forget which is which :)

Comment: understandable!